# Uploading and live video stream to a Spring Boot endpoint, by example

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-live-streaming

I am interested in building a Spring Boot (Java 11) web service that has a controller/resource that exposes an API endpoint for accepting **streaming video**. Particularly I am interested in accomplishing this over HTTP/HLS. The idea is that clients could livestream a video feed to this endpoint, and the endpoint would be doing realtime video processing on it.

When you Google "java spring streaming video" you get a bazillion hits for either:

- Writing a Spring controller/resource (endpoint) that accepts a **single** (already recorded; a.k.a. **not live**) video file upload as a `MultiPartFile`; or
- Writing a Spring controller/resource (endpoint) that downloads and streams a video by range of bytes, as a `MultiPartFile`; a.k.a. a streaming download to a video player on the client-side

**But this isn't what I want.** I am curious to see how a client would livestream a video (byte after byte) to a service endpoint so that the video's `byte[]` is being constantly read and processed server-side. Maybe I want to run AI/ML detections on the video, or do some type of image/graphics processing. The application doesn't really matter, all I am curious here is how to write a Spring Boot endpoint to handle a livestream video feed from client to server (livestream upload).

Would the client just send the livestream in "chunks" or batches of `MultiPartFile` payloads? Either way, there don't appear to be any guides on how to do this in Spring, and I'm sure its definitely something that Spring could handle. **Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current solution is to have the client buffer streaming A/V until 32K bytes are buffered, and then I defined a `POST` endpoint in Spring Boot that accepts a `MultipartFile` in the request body (the 32K bytes).

The Java code in that resource endpoint then invokes an `@Async` service method that uses [ffmpeg-cli-wrapper](https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper) to append the bytes in the `MultipartFile` to the end of an MP4 file I'm storing in S3.

This is working but I will continue to tweak the buffer size until I have a size/configuration that is a careful balance of POST requests (the client sending chunks of the livestream as `MultipartFiles`) and video processing efficiency.